# Do Troop Academies benefit cloned and robotic troops?

Tags: distant-worlds-legends

Troop Academies give a 50% strength bonus to troops recruited on the planet where the Academy is located. Does the bonus apply to conventional troops only, or do clones and robots benefit from it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can only construct one troop facility (academy, factory, clone lab) per planet.